# Python 3.x Socket Module: "bytes like object not str"

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, networking, tcp

I am in the process of making a simple networking messaging interface, using the Sockets module preinstalled in Python 3.5.1 . The code returns with a

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

The server receives the message, but after that the program crashes with that error^I have done research and am aware of using .encode/.decode('utf-8') but it still returns the same error. The error is on the tcpServer.py file, whose source code will be below. I've read about using b'*string here*' but i don't know if it is applicable to variables. Thank you in advance.

Source:

```
import socket

def Main():
    host = "127.0.0.1"    #makes localhost the host server
    port = 5000           #any random port between 1024 and 65535

    s = socket.socket()   #creates a new socket object
    s.bind((host, port))

    s.listen(1)           #listens for 1 connection

    c, addr = s.accept() #accepts a connection and address

    print("Connection from: ", str(addr))
    while True:
        data = c.recv(1024) #receives bytes from connection with a 1024 buffer
        if not data:
            break
        print("From Client: ",str(data.decode()))
        data = str(data).upper() #overwrites current values in var data with a string of the new data in uppercase
        print("Sending: ",str(data))
        c.send(data) #tells connection to send the data
    c.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main()
```

Comment: Python provides an illuminating traceback when an Exception is encountered, provide that in the body of your question.

Comment: `data = data.upper()` instead of `data = str(data).upper()`.  No need to convert bytes to string if you need bytes.

Comment: `str(data).upper()` returns a `str` needing encoding before being sent. As mentioned, its not necessary to convert the bytes at all in your case.

Comment: thank you dietrich and tdelaney, it works now!